# Problem when trying to use generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a class

```
public abstract class AbstractE<T, E extends Enum<E> & Flags>
{
     public interface Flags{} /*marker interface*/
     //... 
     //other code
}
```

and an interface

```
public interface IXYZAdapter
{
   public <E extends Enum<E> & Flags> Set<E> getFlags();
}
```

Where Flags is an interface defined in AbstractE itself.

M extends AbstractE thus:

```
public class M extends AbstractE<Long, M.EF> implements IXYZAdapter
{
    public enum EF implements AbstractE.Flags{flag1, flag2}
    @Override /*from IXYZAdapter*/
    public Set<M.EF> getFlags()
    {return EnumSet.allOf(EF.class);}
    
}
```

Now, from the main code, I try to get a handle on the interface IXYZAdapter and invoke the getFlags method

```
IXYZAdapter adapter = (IXYZAdapter)m; //where m is an instance of AbstractE
Set s = adapter.getFlags();
```

I get the following compile time error in the main program last line (Set s = adapter.getFlags();)

> invalid inferred types for E; inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
>
> ```
> inferred: AbstractE.Flags
>
> bound(s): java.lang.Enum<AbstractE.Flags>,AbstractE.Flags
> ```

What am I doing wrong?
I am using Java 6

Edited to specify the error location

Comment: what line triggers the compiler error?

Comment: When I try to compile, the line Set s = adapter.getFlags() - generates the error

Comment: what is `return new EnumSet.allOf(EF.class);` supposed to mean/do?

Comment: I removed the "new" keyword before EnumSet.allOf    It was typed in there by mistake

Comment: also your first line `public abstract class AbstractE<T, E extends Enum<E> & Flags>` gives me compiler error, it needs to be `public abstract class AbstractE<T, E extends Enum<E> & AbstractE.Flags>`. please use copy/paste when asking this type of intricate question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public interface IXYZAdapter <E extends Enum<E> & AbstractE.Flags>
{
   public Set<E> getFlags();
}
```

And

```
public class M extends AbstractE<Long, M.EF> implements IXYZAdapter<M.EF> 
{
}
```

Or

```
Set<M.EF> s = adapter.getFlags();
```

The problem is that with `Set s = adapter.getFlags();` The system doesn't know which type to infer for E in IXYZAdapter and thus the E in AbstractE doesn't match.

Edit:

Another option might be:

```
interface IXYZAdapter <E extends Enum<E> & AbstractE.Flags>
{
  public Set<? extends E> getFlags();
}

class M extends AbstractE<Long, M.EF> implements IXYZAdapter<M.EF>
{
  public enum EF implements AbstractE.Flags{flag1, flag2}
  public Set<? extends M.EF> getFlags()
  {return EnumSet.allOf(EF.class);}

}
```

And the call: `Set<? extends AbstractE.Flags> s = adapter.getFlags();`

This would allow you to get a set of flags without casting and force the flags to be declared as enum.

Comment: both of these solutions require that the programmer knows the enum type when calling getFlags, or else there are at least warnings.

Comment: well, that's not really true actually. depends on how you write the main method :) i'll give an example!

Answer (score 0):

using the first solution thomas provided, the main method can be written like this to become warning free without actually **having to know about the enum type**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    M m = new M();
    IXYZAdapter<?> adapter = (IXYZAdapter<?>)m;
    Set<?> flags = adapter.getFlags();
    Iterator<?> it = flags.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't get warnings but you'd still have to cast the elements of the set to `AbstractE.Flags`. In that case I'd change the signature to `Set<? extends AbstractE.Flags> getFlags();` and then call `Set<? extends AbstractE.Flags> s = adapter.getFlags();`.

Comment: could you elaborate? this code worked fine, and i got the names of the enums to print this way. it sounds as though you imply that the above code shouldn't work. am i missing something?

Comment: No, the code above works. But try this: `AbstractE.Flags f = it.next();`. You'd have to do this in your case: `AbstractE.Flags f = (AbstractE.Flags)it.next();`