# Generics and Class<? extends Enum<?>>, EnumSet.allOf(class) vs class.getEnumConstants()

Tags: java, class, generics, enums

I have the following BeanValidation code that works fine, and permits to validate that a bean annotated with:

```
  @EnumValue(enumClass = MyTestEnum.class)
  private String field;

  public enum MyTestEnum {
    VAL1, VAL2;
  }
```

Will be validated only if the field value is "VAL1" or "VAL2".

```
public class EnumNameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EnumValue, String> {

  private Set<String> AVAILABLE_ENUM_NAMES;

  @Override
  public void initialize(EnumValue enumValue) {
    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumSelected = enumValue.enumClass();
    Set<? extends Enum<?>> enumInstances = Sets.newHashSet(enumSelected.getEnumConstants());
    AVAILABLE_ENUM_NAMES = FluentIterable
            .from(enumInstances)
            .transform(PrimitiveGuavaFunctions.ENUM_TO_NAME)
            .toImmutableSet();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if ( value == null ) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return AVAILABLE_ENUM_NAMES.contains(value);
    }
  }

}
```

What I don't understand is why my first attempt failed. Using instead of the `enumSelected.getEnumConstants()` above the following code:

```
Set<? extends Enum<?>> enumInstances = EnumSet.allOf(enumSelected);
```

Intellij 12 doesn't highlight any error, but the compiler says:

```
java: method allOf in class java.util.EnumSet<E> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Class<E>
  found: java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Enum<?>>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Enum<?>
    bound(s): java.lang.Enum<capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Enum<?>>
```

---

I don't understand the problem, and I also have that code which works fine:

```
  private static <T extends Enum<T> & EnumAlternativeName> T safeGetByAlternativeName(Class<T> enumClass, String alternativeName) {
    for ( T t : EnumSet.allOf(enumClass) ) {
      if ( t.getAlternativeName().equals(alternativeName) ) {
        return t;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Related ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548091/problem-when-trying-to-use-generics

Comment: This one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy: Ticket?  Is StackOverflow a support system now :)

Comment: @mellamokb I was using Trac simultaneously and the 5 min limit was over when I wanted to fix that :P and yes at times it looks like a support system if you know what I mean...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that in `? extends Enum<?>` the two `?` could be different whereas `allOf` expects a `T extends Enum<T>` where both `T` are the same.

For example, consider the following code:

```
static enum MyEnum {}
static class EnumValue<T extends Enum<T>> {
    Class<T> enumClass;
    EnumValue(Class<T> enumClass) {
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }
    Class<T> enumClass() { return enumClass; }
}
```

These lines will compile:

```
EnumValue<?> enumValue = new EnumValue(MyEnum.class); // raw constructor
Set<? extends Enum<?>> enumInstances = EnumSet.allOf(enumValue.enumClass());
```

because we know that the two `T` in `enumValue.enumClass()` are the same but this won't:

```
EnumValue enumValue = new EnumValue(MyEnum.class);
Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumSelected = enumValue.enumClass();
Set<? extends Enum<?>> enumInstances = EnumSet.allOf(enumSelected);
```

because you have lost information by using a `Class<? extends Enum<?>>` as an intermediate step.

Comment: thanks, I guess I have no choice then because I can't make that enum attribute of the annotation being EnumValue<T extends Enum<T>>

Answer (score 4):

My explanation on @assylias's solution:

What we want to express about the type of the class is that it's a

```
Class<E>, for some E, that E <: Enum<E>
```

but Java does not allow us to introduce a type variable `E` in a method body.

Usually, we can exploit wildcard and wildcard capture to introduce a hidden type variable

```
class G<T extends b(T)> { ... }  // b(T) is a type expression that may contain T

G<? extends A>   --capture-->   G<T>, for some T, that T <: A & b(T)
```

But this won't work in our case, since `T` in `Class<T>` does not have a bound that makes it work.

So we need to introduce a new type with the desired bound

```
class EnumClass<E extends Enum<E>>   // called EnumValue in assylias's solution

    EnumClass(Class<E> enumClass) 

    Class<E> enumClass()

EnumClass<?>   --capture-->    EnumClass<E>, for some E, that E <: Enum<E>
```

We then call `EnumClass<E>.enumClass()` to yield a

```
Class<E>, for some E, that E <: Enum<E>
```

which is the goal we've been trying to achieve.

But how can we call the constructor of `EnumClass`? The origin of the problem is that we don't have a proper type for `enumClass`, yet the constructor of `EnumClass` wants a properly typed `enumClass`.

```
Class<not-proper> enumClass = ...;
new EnumClass<...>(enumClass);  // wont work
```

Fortunately(?) the raw type helps here which disables generics type checking

```
EnumClass raw = new EnumClass(enumClass);  // no generics
EnumClass<?> wild = raw;
```

So the minimum gymnastics we need to perform to cast the class to the desired type is

```
((EnumClass<?>)new EnumClass(enumClass)).enumClass()
```

Comment: +1 Good explanation. I'm wondering if `EnumClass<?> wild = new EnumClass<>(enumClass);` works in Java 7.