# I can't compile a Guava's Cache's builder because of Java generics

Tags: java, generics, guava

I have the following short, self-contained code that shows an error at compile time. I've desperately tried to have it compiling. I usually don't have trouble with generics anymore, but well I give up on this one and I ask the help of the team.

```
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader;
import com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache;

public class CacheWithGenericsDoesNotCompile {

  // Class definition can't be modified
  static class Resource<T extends Resource<T>> {}

  // Class definition can't be modified
  static class ResourceType<T extends Resource<T>> {
    public ResourceType(Class<T> type) {}
  }

  // Variable definition may be modified
  static LoadingCache<Class<? extends Resource<?>>, ResourceType<? extends Resource<?>>> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(
      new CacheLoader<Class<? extends Resource<?>>, ResourceType<? extends Resource<?>>>() {
        @Override public ResourceType<? extends Resource<?>> load(Class<? extends Resource<?>> key) throws Exception {
          return new ResourceType<? extends Resource<?>>(key);
        }
    });

  // Method definition can't be modified, method content may.
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  static <T extends Resource<T>> ResourceType<T> getResourceType(Class<T> type) {
    return (ResourceType<T>)cache.getUnchecked(type);
  }
}
```

The line that fails to compile is:

```
return new ResourceType<? extends Resource<?>>(key);
```

I know why it fails: I may not write `new Xxxx<...>` with a question mark (`?`). I just can't write this line differently to have the other lines compiling.

I have a fallback solutions in the case where `Resource` has no generics, but in the limit of the possible I'd like to keep `Resource` with generics.

I have no restriction about the generics of the `LoadingCache` except that I need it to be called as in `getResourceType(Class)`.

So... how can I fix this code?

Comment: Ah, what I was missing was the recursive bounds (`T extends Resource<T>`) being lost by the limitations of wildcard capture, which is why my answer didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution with some ignored warning :

```
  static LoadingCache<Class<? extends Resource<?>>, ResourceType<? extends Resource<?>>> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(
      new CacheLoader<Class<? extends Resource<?>>, ResourceType<? extends Resource<?>>>() {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        @Override public ResourceType<? extends Resource<?>> load(Class<? extends Resource<?>> key) throws Exception {
          return new ResourceType(key);
        }
    });
```

As suggested by  [@John B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905762/john-b) in a comment. This code is not different at **run-time** than the code in the question due to [type-erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: As an added point, the above is no different at run-time than the code in the question due to type-erasure so no reason not to use it.

Comment: Yes it compiles and does the job. Thanks!

Comment: As distasteful as raw types are, they're probably an acceptable approach here. For the cache to be statically type-safe, it'd require a constraint between the keys and values that the generics system can't express at all, so it makes sense to just "not use" generics.

Answer (score 1):

I played a bit more with gontard's solution (so if you upvote this, make sure to upvote gontard's answer too) and millimoose's comment. I came to this solution which removes the generics completely, for a far more readable code.

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
static LoadingCache<Class, ResourceType> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(
    new CacheLoader<Class, ResourceType>() {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      @Override public ResourceType load(Class key) throws Exception {
        return new ResourceType(key);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If we can cast `key` to a proper type

```
Class<T> for some T that T<:Resource<T>
```

then we have no problem to write

```
ResourceType<? extends Resource<?>> result = new ResourceType<>(casted_key)
```

Usually this kind of casting can be done through wildcard capture, but it doesn't work if the type variable has a self referential bound. See the workaround at [Generics and Class<? extends Enum<?>>, EnumSet.allOf(class) vs class.getEnumConstants()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366375/generics-and-class-extends-enum-enumset-allofclass-vs-class-getenumcons) .